# Change the date of a photo through the graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, date, facebook-timeline

In the Facebook timeline I am happy that I can now manually change the dates of previous photos that I have posted. But I would love to be able to do this through the graph API. I cannot see any exposed properties, though, when I look at the JSON data for one of these entries that I've already changed, and there is nothing documented here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

created_time and updated_time don't change even when you manually change the date of an entry. Is there a hidden property that isn't documented yet?

Comment: I met with the folks of 1000memories.com last week, and they said they  were able to do this. But their demo failed when I wanted to see it...  Like you, I haven't been able to find anything in the API, but will post here if I find anything.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that it's a limitation of the public Facebook API.  You should submit is as a bug to facebook to let them have a look at it.